# In Java, how do you create a method which takes an array set to a given length?

Tags: arrays, methods

I know how to create a method,
which takes an array

`public void x(int [] arr){}`

but I do not know how to set a given length to that array.

Comment: where do you want to set length, it seems that your questions is incomplete. will you please make it more clear, so that you will be helped more accurately?

Comment: What’s language are you using? c,c#,c++,java,...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make a method that accepts an array, you can structure it like this:

```
public void x (int[] arr) {
    // Code
}
```

If you want to restrict the length of array the method can accept, you could do something similar to this:

```
public void x (int[] arr) {
    //Check to see if arr is a satisfactory length
    if (arr.length > 10) {
        //Throw an exception, break, print to the console etc...
    }
}
```

There are some areas where I can't make this explanation as detailed because I don't know what language you're programming in.

Comment: I meant when u made int[] arr, how would you give that array a specific length.

Comment: @NicholasChen just do int[] arr = new int[length_you_want];

Comment: but what if I want to put it in parameters of a method?

Comment: @NicholasChen int[] is just a type, it is not an actual array. In the parameters, you’re just giving specifying what kinds of objects your method will accept and giving them names you you can refer to them inside of your method. To reiterate, you’re not making a new array in the method header. You can use the code from my previous comment and put it in the body of your method to achieve what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much! So basically, I should set the array length in the method?